# Store Application Preference Android

Tags: android

I have added a mute button to a menu on my application and am wondering if it is possible to store the user's latest preference of either muted or unmuted for use when he/she reopens the application.

Here is the code I am using for setting mute or umute:

```
public void isMute() {

      if(mIsMute){    
          mAm.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);
          mIsMute = false;

      }else{
          mAm.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
          mIsMute = true;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to store the state. Read it when application starts and set current state.

I modified a little example from [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

```
public class Calc extends Activity {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle state){         
       super.onCreate(state);
       . . .

       // Restore preferences
       SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
       mIsMute = settings.getBoolean("IsMute", false);
       isMute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
       super.onStop();

      // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
      // All objects are from android.context.Context
      SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
      editor.putBoolean("IsMute", mIsMute);

      // Commit the edits!
      editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this.  I have updated my original question with my method that sets mute or unmute.  Would I need to store the result in SharePreferences and call to see what is there in my init()?

Comment: First, thank you for your help...I have it working kinda.  By kinda I mean that every time I start my app it is muted even if I  closed my app while unmuted.  I tried switching the value in the putBoolean to no avail.  Any ideas?

Comment: Show me the code. See in debugger or log what value have mIsMute after you doing mIsMute = settings.getBoolean("IsMute", false); if it's true then something wrong with isMute() function or you set it to false in another place after.

Comment: I "Answered" my own so I could include all my code and such for anyone to look at.  Still not working, but on my way.